# How to trigger some functionality for incoming messages on RabbitMQ

Tags: c#, asp.net, rabbitmq, monitoring

Whenever rabbitMq Receives any messages it should trigger some functionality.
How can i achieve this ?

Comment: As per the [Docs](https://www.rabbitmq.com/dotnet-api-guide.html#consuming) , one of the simplest methods with the Rabbit .Net client is to use the `EventingBasicConsumer` and handle the `Received` event. Even higher level abstractions are possible using extra, albeit opinionated libraries such as [EasyNetQ](http://easynetq.com/)

Comment: Yes it works thank You

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can use receive event to do the functionality.
Below code sample shows how to do the same.

```
     ConnectionFactory oFactory = new ConnectionFactory();
     oFactory.UserName = oRabbitMQData.userName;
     oFactory.Password = oRabbitMQData.password;
     oFactory.VirtualHost = oRabbitMQData.virtualHost;
     oFactory.HostName = oRabbitMQData.hostName;
     oFactory.Port = oRabbitMQData.port;

     var connection = oFactory.CreateConnection();

     var channel = connection.CreateModel();
     // setup signal
     var signal = new ManualResetEvent(true);

     oRabbitMQConnections.Add(connection);
     oRabbitMQChannels.Add(channel);

     var consumer = new EventingBasicConsumer(channel);
     byte[] messageBody = null;

     consumer.Received += (sender, args) =>
     {

        messageBody = args.Body;
        string sMsg = UTF8Encoding.UTF8.GetString(messageBody);

        // process your message or store for later
        // set signal

        channel.BasicAck(args.DeliveryTag, false);

       // Do something

        signal.Set();
     };

     // start consuming
     channel.BasicConsume(oRabbitMQData.queueName, false, consumer);
```